# Pattern matching against a string property

Tags: f#

I'm de-serializing some mappings from JSON and later on I need to pattern match based on a `string` field of the de-serialized types like this:

```ml
let mappings = getWorkItemMappings

let result =
  workItemMappings
  |> Seq.find (fun (m: WorkItemMapping) -> m.Uuid = workTime.workItemUuid)

  match mapping.Name with
```

Even if I complete the pattern match for all cases I still get `Incomplete pattern matches on this expression.`. Which is obvious to me due to the string type of the `Name` field.

Is there a way tell the compiler which values for the `Name` field are available?.

I think I could create a union type for the possible mapping types and try to de-serialize the JSON to this union type but I would like to if there's another option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are pattern matching on a string value, the compiler has no static guarantee that it will only have certain values, because it is always possible to construct a string of a different value. The fact that it comes from JSON does not help - you may always have an invalid JSON.

The best option is to add a default case which throws a custom descriptive exception. Either one that you handle somewhere else (to indicate that the JSON file was invalid) or (if you check the validity elsewhere) something like this:

```
let parseFood f = 
  match f with
  | "burger" -> 1
  | "pizza" -> 2
  | _ -> raise(invalidArg "f" $"Expected burger or pizza but got {f}")
```

Note that the F# compiler is *very* cautious. It does not even let you handle enum values using pattern matching, because under the cover, there are ways of creating invalid enum values! For example:

```
type Foo = 
  | A = 1

let f (a:Foo) = 
  match a with 
  | Foo.A -> 0
```

> warning FS0104: Enums may take values outside known cases. For example, the value 'enum (0)' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to understand what you're asking. Maybe this snippet can be of help. It demos how literal string constants can be used in pattern matching, and reused in functions. This gives some added safety and readability when adding and removing cases. If you prefer not to serialize a DU directly, then perhaps this is useful as part of the solution.

```
type MyDu =
    | A
    | B
    | C

let [<Literal>] A' = "A"
let [<Literal>] B' = "B"
let [<Literal>] C' = "C"

let strToMyDuOption (s: string) =
    match s with
    | A' -> Some A
    | B' -> Some B
    | C'-> Some C
    | _ -> None
    
let strToMyDu (s: string) =
    match s with
    | A' -> A
    | B' -> B
    | C'-> C
    | s -> failwith $"MyDu case {s} is unknown."

let myDuToStr (x: MyDu) =
    match x with
    | A -> A'
    | B -> B'
    | C -> C'

// LINQPad
let dump x = x.Dump()

strToMyDuOption A' |> dump
strToMyDuOption "x" |> dump

myDuToStr A |> dump
```